# How to make an eclipse plugin load on startup

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have an Eclipse plugin based RCP application. I want to add one plugin in it and I want that it should be initialized as soon as the application is launched (and not lazy initialization).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a 3.x style RCP use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point to specify a class which implements `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup`. This will be called early on in Eclipse start up.